# why InvocationExpression's Arguments is Expression rather than ParameterExpression?

Tags: c#

if you look at the source code of `InvocationExpression`

```
public sealed class InvocationExpression : Expression, IArgumentProvider
{
   public Expression Expression { get; }
   public ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> Arguments { get; }
}
```

why it is not `public ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> Arguments { get; }`, just like what `LambdaExpression` is, isn't that the `Arguments` in `InvocationExpression` the same thing as `Parameters` in `LambdaExpression`?

```
public abstract class LambdaExpression : Expression
{
   public Expression Body { get; }
   public ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> Parameters { get; }
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters and arguments aren't the same thing. A parameter is part of the declaration of a method, constructor, lambda expression etc. An argument is an expression evaluated to obtain the initial value of a parameter - and it can generally be *any* expression that's convertible to the appropriate type. If the `Arguments` property were of type `ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression>`, you'd only be able to use parameters as invocation arguments... so you *would* be able to create an expression tree like this:

```cs
Expression<Action<string>> x = p => Console.WriteLine(p);
```

(because the expression `p` is a parameter expression)... but you wouldn't be able to write this:

```cs
Expression<Action<string>> x = p => Console.WriteLine("Hello " + p);
```

... because `"Hello " + p` (the argument to `Console.WriteLine`) isn't a parameter; it's a binary addition operation.